# Masking multiple shapes using globalCompositeOperation in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I am attempting to draw multiple rectangles and then mask those using globalCompositeOperation 'source-in' which works great, but the issue is that when i fill my rectangles they disappear... If I only have one fill() call they all draw properly but only respect the last fill style applied.

code in question -

```
ctx.drawImage(self.glass.mask, 256, 375);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

ctx.rect(256, 635, 256, 75);
ctx.fillStyle = "#c65127";

ctx.rect(256, 605, 256, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = "#f5f4f0";

ctx.rect(256, 565, 256, 35);
ctx.fillStyle = "#c65127";

ctx.fill();
```

The code above works properly. But if I do this, and remove the mask -

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 256, 256, 75);
ctx.fillStyle = "#c65127";
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 226, 256, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = "#f5f4f0";
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 186, 256, 35);
ctx.fillStyle = "#222";
ctx.fill();
```

I have each rectangle and they respect their fill styles. Problem is when I enable the mask they are no longer visible.

Is there a limitation to the number of elements you can have under globalCompositeOperation 'source-in' or am I just missing something simple?

here are some fiddles -

http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/ - working as expected but not respecting the fill styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/1/ - Removing mask to show all elements

http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/2/ - Adding beginPath() and fill() elements respect fill styles. ( no masking)

http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/3/ - Adding the mask back ( nothing shows up anymore )

http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/4/ - Only having one rectangle with the same code as #3 works properly.

Comment: Tampered with this for a while, tried using `ctx.closePath()` after each shape, tried using multiple masks and multiple `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` and different composite types.... nothin.

Comment: @inorganik That's exactly what I've noticed. Seems that there is an issue when drawing multiple shapes with different fill styles. Unless there is something super simple that I am missing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I believe the issue is with globalCompositeOperation 'source-in'. What I wound up doing was creating a buffer canvas which I draw my shapes on, then taking that image data and drawing it into my primary canvas and apply the GCO to that.

here's a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ENtXs/5/

code in question:

```
// Canvas and Buffers
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var buffer = document.getElementById('buffer');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var buffer_ctx = buffer.getContext('2d');

// sizing
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

buffer.height = window.innerHeight;
buffer.width = window.innerWidth;

// mask image
var mask = new Image();
mask.onload = function () {
    drawBuffer();
}

mask.src = 'http://drewdahlman.com/experiments/masking/highball_mask.png';

function drawBuffer() {
    buffer_ctx.beginPath();
    buffer_ctx.rect(0, 256, 256, 75);
    buffer_ctx.fillStyle = "#c65127";
    buffer_ctx.fill();

    buffer_ctx.beginPath();
    buffer_ctx.rect(0, 226, 256, 25);
    buffer_ctx.fillStyle = "#f5f4f0";
    buffer_ctx.fill();

    buffer_ctx.beginPath();
    buffer_ctx.rect(0, 186, 256, 35);
    buffer_ctx.fillStyle = "#222";
    buffer_ctx.fill();

    var image = buffer.toDataURL("image/png");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        buffer_ctx.clearRect(0,0,buffer.width,buffer.height);
        ctx.drawImage(mask,0,0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src = image;
}
```